# Validate consecutive numbers in column, based on category in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a DataFrame with the following structure:

```
data = {'alpha_3_id': ['LIA', 'LIA', 'LIA', 'LIA', 'MIL', 'MIL', 'DEA', 'DEA', 'DEA', 'DEA'],
        'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4]
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

  alpha_3_id  id
0        LIA   1
1        LIA   2
2        LIA   3
3        LIA   4
4        MIL   1
5        MIL   2
6        DEA   1
7        DEA   2
8        DEA   3
9        DEA   4
```

I need to validate that for each "alpha_3_id", numbers in column "id" are listed in a consecutive order.

I tried to do this using code below but it only works if all values in column are consecutive but I need to test it for each category (LIA, MIL DEA, etc).

```
all(j == i + 1 for i, j in zip(list_of_values, list_of_values[1:]))
```

Comment: First value always starting `1` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For test consecutive values use custom lambda function with [`Series.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) with omit first value and test if all values are `1` by [`Series.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.all.html):

```
out = df.groupby('alpha_3_id')['id'].apply(lambda x: x.diff().iloc[1:].eq(1).all())
print (out)
alpha_3_id
DEA    True
LIA    True
MIL    True
Name: id, dtype: bool

out = df.groupby('alpha_3_id')['id'].apply(lambda x: x.diff().iloc[1:].eq(1).all()).all()
print (out)
True
```

Another idea is use [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html), remove first values per groups by [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html), test by `1` and last use [`Series.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.all.html):

```
out = df.groupby('alpha_3_id')['id'].diff()[df['alpha_3_id'].duplicated()].eq(1).all()
print (out)
True
```

Comment: I realize now you have used something similar, just to let you know that I had this alternative ready

Comment: @mozway - Sure, I see it.

Answer (score 1):

Another per-group comparison with [`np.array_equal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_equal.html):

```
df.groupby('alpha_3_id')['id'].agg(lambda x: np.array_equal(x, range(x.values[0], x.size + 1)))
```

---

```
alpha_3_id
DEA    True
LIA    True
MIL    True
Name: id, dtype: bool
```

---

Quick measurements:

```
In [40]: %timeit df.groupby('alpha_3_id')['id'].apply(lambda x: x.diff().iloc[1:].eq(1).all())
851 µs ± 4.29 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

In [41]: %timeit df.groupby('alpha_3_id')['id'].agg(lambda s: (np.diff(s)==1).all())
368 µs ± 1.15 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

In [42]: %timeit df.groupby('alpha_3_id')['id'].agg(lambda x: np.array_equal(x, range(x.values[0], x.size + 1)))
357 µs ± 2.55 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Comment: Better is use `df.groupby('alpha_3_id')['id'].agg(lambda x: np.array_equal(x, range(x.min(), x.size + 1)))`

Comment: @jezrael, yes, it should be `range(x.values[0], x.size + 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to check if all groups are in the form 1/2/3, you can use [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df['id'].eq(df.groupby('alpha_3_id').cumcount().add(1)).all()
```

Output `True`

Per group, using [`numpy.diff`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html):

```
out = df.groupby('alpha_3_id')['id'].agg(lambda s: (np.diff(s)==1).all())
```

Output:

```
alpha_3_id
DEA    True
LIA    True
MIL    True
Name: id, dtype: bool
```

Fix of you approach (not efficient though):

```
def valid(s):
    list_of_values = s.tolist()
    return all(j == i + 1 for i, j in zip(list_of_values, list_of_values[1:]))

df.groupby('alpha_3_id')['id'].agg(valid)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use shift within groups and compare original values with `shifted - 1`. However, NAs occur after shifting in the end of each group, so we can fill the NAs with the original values.

```
all(df["id"] == (df.groupby("alpha_3_id").id.shift(-1) - 1).fillna(df["id"]))
```

Output:

```
True
```